# How to define operators on $\ell^p_{00}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given $p\in (1,\infty)$. Take a bounded sequence $(f_n)$ in $\ell^p$ and define a linear map $T\colon \ell^p_{00}\to \ell^p$ ($\ell^p_{00}$ is the space of finitelty supported sequences in $\ell^p$) by

$Te_n = f_n$

($e_n$ is the usual (Hamel) basis for $\ell^p_{00}$).

Is $T$ a bounded linear map? If $p=1$, the answer is yes... If not, what do have to assume on $(f_n)$ to get boundeness of $T$?

Comment: In $\ell^2_{00}$ try $f_n = e_1$ for all $n$.  So you do need some assumptions on $f_n$.  Even in $\ell_2$ I think there is no simple criterion.  "Simple" meaning easier than writing down the definition for a bounded operator.

Comment: Edgar's example should work in all $\ell^p_{00}$ (as for no $p > 1$ it holds that $n = \|ne_1\|_p \le Cn^{1/p} = C\|(1,\ldots, 1,0,\ldots)\|_p$ is true for all $n$).

Comment: $T$ will for example (to give a sufficent criterion) be bounded if the $f_n$ are disjointly supported as then $\|T(\sum_i x_i e_i)\|_p^p = \|\sum_i x_i f_i\|_p^p = \sum_i \|x_i f_i\|_p^p \le M^p\sum_i |x_i|^p = M^p\|x\|_p^p$ for all $x \in \ell^p_{00}$ where $M$ is some upper bound of the $\|f_i\|_p$.

Comment: One nontrivial sufficient condition is the Schur Test ($p=2$), which you can find, for example, in Conway's *Course in Functional Analysis*. [The Wikipedia article states it in the integral form only.]